# Puppeteer doesn't show some images

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have a lambda function that makes screenshots for me. And I noticed that puppeteer can't load some images. Image just blank with alt tag instead of the image. Here an example of the page with one image where it doesn't work: https://memorina.ru/example.html

The easiest place to try it is run code below in this page: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

```
async function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://memorina.ru/example.html");

console.log(await page.content());
await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
});
await timeout(15000);
await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});

await browser.close();
```

I've tried to add timeout and scroll, but it doesn't work. Is there any ideas why it doesn't work for that image?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:
I was using old browser. It seems like headless chrome has problems with webp format and they were fixed in latest library.
So in "chrome-aws-lambda": "^5.5.0", "puppeteer-core": "^5.5.0" everything is working fine.